# Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1 customer login not working in chrome browser

Tags: magento2, cookie, customer-session, customer-login, issue

Dear Friends I am not able to login in magento 2 customer login and not getting any error message also. customer login working fine in firefox browser

Comment: are you on localhost ? using localhost as a server name ?

Comment: My website on server(domain) not on localhost

Comment: @SURENDERSINGH did you get any solution for this? I'm facing same issue in 2.3.4

Comment: @AsadKhan Yes I had issue in Payu Plugin. so removed payu extension and now login working fine in all browser. you can disable one by one all the extension and can check.

Comment: @SURENDERSINGH what is the Payu Plugin is it existing pluging?